# How to change foreground and background colors of selection text in Visual Basic 2022 dark mode text editor

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

How can I change the foreground and background colors of text that I selected by double-clicking?   I cannot find this in tools > options > Env.. > Fonts..

My VS is set for dark mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tools > options > Env.. > Fonts and Colors.
Choose **Selected Text** in Display items.
Foreground color of Selected text cannot be changed.

[image]